# How to delete a document of Firestore in Android Studio with Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

The aim of this application is to delete the entire document from the Firestore when entering the document's name such as the uid.

The following image shows the code that I used to delete the document.

```
firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    button_deleteByID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            userID = editText_userID.getText().toString();
            Log.d("userID", userID);

            //delete document function
            DocumentReference documentReference = firestore.collection("Users").document(userID);
            documentReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    Log.d("delete successfully","delete successfully");
                    Toast.makeText(Delete.this, "delete successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d("failed", "delete failed");
                }
            });



        }
    });
```

The structure of the Firestore is shown below:
[image: firestore]

After running this code, the Logcat shows a message "delete successfully". But the problem is that the document is not deleted in the Firestore. Any solution for it? Thanks.

Comment: edit question send code i answer you

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: send code here i solve you

Comment: What have you tried so far in code? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Hi, sir. The question has been updated. Hope you can take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this code put to your adapter on delete button

userId means your model_list like

```
userId = fileModelList.get(position).getUserId()
```

```
deleteFileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog)
                    .setTitle("Delete File")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure, you want to delete this file?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
                                                .document(userID).delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    fileModelList.remove(position);
                                                    fileAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                } else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
    }
});
```